# iphone email link not selected correctly

Tags: iphone, email, hyperlink

I'm creating a link to open my App and pass some data in the URL.

When I add the query parameter ? my link get broken.

```
NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:dataFilePath];
NSString *encodedString = [GTMBase64 stringByWebSafeEncodingData:fileData padded:YES];
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myApp://localhost/backup?%@", 
encodedString];
```

the link is quite long, but also a shorter one doesn't work:

```
myApp://localhost/backup?PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiPz48bG9jPjxpbmdyZWRpZW50VHlwZS
```

and when the e-mail appears in the iPhone, only this is underlined and act as a link:

```
myApp://localhost/
```

Adding the query as NeilInglis suggest it doesn't work also, the link is broken at same place.

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myApp://localhost/backup?query=%@",
encodedString];
```

The Html is ON or OFF, it doesn't affect.

If I enocode the URL it also doesn't work ...

Don't know what I can try next ...

any ideas ?

thanks ...

regards,

r.

Answer (score 0):

Try mapping the query parameter to a name.

@"myApp://localhost/backup?**queryParamName**=%@

Comment: it doesn't work also, the link is broken before the ?

I get only myApp://localhost/

thanks,